# "slow speaker" auf Deutsch

Tags: word-choice, phrase, meaning

Wie erkläre ich mich auf gut Deutsch, daß ich leider kein fließend Deutsch spreche?

Wie heißt "slow speaker" auf Deutsch?

Comment: Ich konnte *slow speaker* nicht als feststehenden Begriff finden, der etwas anderes als die Summe seiner Teile ist. Kannst Du erläutern, was Du damit meinst?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Kann leider es nicht erläutern. Vlt diese Frage fordert etwas geändert zu sein.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dein Satz etwas anders:

> Ich spreche (leider) nicht fließend Deutsch.
>   Leider spreche ich nicht fließend Deutsch.

Weitere Alternativen:

> Ich bin ein Anfänger in Deutsch.
>   Mein Deutsch ist (leider) nicht sehr gut.

Sich als langsam zu bezeichnen - egal in welcher Hinsicht -, würde ich nicht empfehlen.

Aus den Kommentaren:

> Ich bin noch ein Anfänger in Deutsch.
>   Ich bin noch nicht so gut in Deutsch.
>   Leider ist mein Deutsch nicht sehr gut.
>   Leider spreche ich Deutsch nicht fließend.

Note that saying "Noch spreche ich leider nicht fließend" suggests a higher level of fluency.

Comment: Optional könnte man auch ein "noch" hinzufügen, um den Lernwillen zu betonen.

Comment: It’s more idiomatic to put _Deutsch_ directly before _nicht_.

Comment: @Hulk Yeah, you're absolutely right! Thanks for advice!

Answer (score 2):

"slow speaker" = "Langsamsprecher"(deutsch)
Wenn du meinst, dass du nicht schnell sprechen kannst, würde ich zu 
"Ich spreche nicht fließend Deutsch" oder
"Ich spreche nicht flüssig  Deutsch" 
raten.
"Mein Deutsch ist nicht gut" könntest du aber auch verwenden.